# Ingres SQL date difference

Tags: sql, date-format, date-difference, ingres

I need to find the difference between two dates in minutes. Here is the select statement I have been using:

```
 select date ('05.04.2017  11:12:00') - date('now');
```

It is returning `-4 mins -21 secs` but I want to see just 4 minutes. I could not  find the answer in the ref guide, any idea how to show it in the format I need?

Answer (score 5):

http://ariel.its.unimelb.edu.au/~yuan/Ingres/us_13229.html

can you give this a shot... not familiar with ingres

```
select    INTERVAL('mins','today'-date('05.04.2017  11:12:00'))
```

http://www.r20.nl/TheSQLGuidetoIngres-AppendixB.pdf

Comment: Good answer. If the result wanted is simply 4, you could include some extra functions, eg: select abs(int(round(interval('mins',date('2017-01-01 11:55:39')-date('2017-01-01 12:00:00')),0)));