# date difference in minutes for Ingres

Tags: sql, date-difference, ingres, actian

I have DB (ingres 11) which works with ANSI i need to findout difference in minutes between dates, I have statement

```
SELECT  top 10  date('now') - '06.07.2017 10:20:02'
```

itscalculating  and returning  me this `186 days 22 hrs 43 mins` how i can convert it  to number of minutes ?

Comment: Maybe useful? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43219383/ingres-sql-date-difference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution was easy

```
SELECT  top 10  TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,date('now'),'06.07.2017 10:20:02')
```